# Where is the place mentioned in John 14:2-3?

Tags: john

John 14:2-3 ASV

> In my Father's house are many mansions; if it were not so, I would
> have told you; for I go to prepare a place for you And if I go and
> prepare a place for you, I come again, and will receive you unto
> myself; that where I am, there ye may be also.

Where is this place that Jesus said he will prepare, come to and be with his followers?

Comment: @Dottard. Are you sure?

Comment: I believe this would be in reference to the Revelation chapter 21 "new Jerusalem".

Comment: @MarkVestal . . . yes, indeed, . . .  which is on a new earth under a new heavens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my translation of John 14:1-3 -

> Let not your hearts be troubled! [why?]
>
> - You believe in God
> - You also believe in Me
> - In My Father's house are many dwelling-places (if not I would have told you)
> - I am going to prepare a place for you
> - If I am going to prepare a place for you, I am coming again and will receive you to Myself
> - So that where I am you also may be

The clear allusion/model in John 14:1-3 is based on the ancient eastern wedding ritual - see appendix below.

The following considerations suggest that the "place" is in the Father's house in heaven:

- John 14:2 & 3 actually says that "the place" is in the Father's house.
- Jesus taught His disciples to pray, "Our Father in heaven", Matt 6:9, Luke 11:2.  See also Matt 5:45, 48, 10:33, 12:50, 18:4, 23:9, Mark 11:26, etc, which also describe the Father as being in heaven.
- Jesus claimed to come from heaven and was returning to heaven, John 3:13, 31, 6:38, 46, 61, 62, 8:38, 13:1, 3, 16:27, 28, Heb 1:2, 3, etc.
- In Heb 11:14-16, the home of the saved is described as a "better county, a heavenly one", because God has prepared a city for them.
- Rev 3:12, 21:2 describes this city as the "New Jerusalem" which ultimately comes from heaven to earth.

Therefore, the "place" Jesus alludes to is in heaven with the Father.

**APPENDIX - Ancient Wedding Sequence**

The metaphor of marriage (especially in John 14:1-3) assumes the following sequence of events:

1. A man decides to marry a young woman
2. He promises to marry her, and provide for her, and many other benefits
3. He then goes away to build her a house for their marriage and expected family - most often an extension of his father's house
4. During this "waiting time" the engaged woman is expected to make herself ready, remain faithful to her husband and wait for his return
5. The husband is also expected to arrange a marriage feast and ceremony, complete with invited guests
6. The husband returns at an unexpected time to claim his bride and enjoy the wedding feast
7. After the wedding, the husband takes the new bride to the home he has just completed to live with him

Comment: The verse does not say that Jesus will take the believers to heaven. Just to clarify, does the home that you mentioned on your point #7, does "home" there mean heaven too?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - Jesus says He will take believes to the Father's house which is where "the place" is being prepared.  The other verses say that the father is in heaven and that Jesus is going to heaven.  Follow the sequence.  The point #7 is about a typical eastern wedding, not Jesus' destiny.

Comment: Bible hub show that take is not the meaning of paralombano. welcome
παραλήμψομαι (paralēmpsomai)
Verb - Future Indicative Middle - 1st Person Singular
Strong's 3880: From para and lambano; to receive near, i.e. Associate with oneself; by analogy, to assume an office; figuratively, to learn.

Comment: @AlexBalilo - that is why I translated it "will receive" - look at what I have written, please!

Comment: I looked at what you have written, but you also commented " Jesus says He will take believes to the Father's house which is where "the place" is being prepared." So where is Jesus coming to receive his believers? In heaven?

Comment: @AlexBalilo - Jesus is returning to earth (as He left, Acts 1:11) to receive us to be with Him in His Father's house in heaven.  1 Thess 4:16, 17.

Comment: I'm prevented from further discussing. There is nothing in this verse that support your idea of " Jesus is returning to earth (as He left, Acts 1:11) to receive us to be with Him in His Father's house in heaven. 1 Thess 4:16, 17."  He receives us on earth, but it does not say that Jesus receives us to be with him in his Father's house in heaven.

Comment: Is it really appropriate to use wedding custom to understand what Jesus is saying? Obviously the custom is as you describe, but in what way can you say Jesus is making an allusion to marrying the disciples? Also the discourse continues *I will not leave you fatherless...* (v. 18) and the Father and Jesus will *come and make a home with them.* (v. 23) The allusion to marriage does not appear to apply.

Comment: @RevelationLad - quite the contrary - Jesus comes to marry the church, His bride as per Rev 12 & 19.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe the disciples at the Last Supper would understand what Jesus said as marrying **them.** And Revelation wasn't written until long after. Retrospectively, perhaps but still unlikely. At the Last Supper? Impossible.

Comment: @RevelationLad - the symbols of Revelation are taken from the OT.  Israel is there depicted as the bride of God, Isa 62:5, Jer 2:1, 2.  See also Isa 47:1-3, Jer 2:32, Eze 16, Nah 3:4, 5

Answer (score 0):

The  Bible talks that the dwelling place of God is in heaven, we read:

1 Kings 8:43 NASB

43 hear in heaven Your dwelling place, and act in accordance with all for which the foreigner calls to You, in order that all the peoples of the earth may know Your name, to [a]fear You, as do Your people Israel, and that they may know that [b]this house which I have built is called by Your name.

Jesus accented to heaven 40 days after his resurrection's to appear before God in the heavens.

Hebrews 9:24 NASB

24 For Christ did not enter a holy place made by hands, a mere copy of the true one, but into heaven itself, now to appear in the presence of God for us;

Jesus taught his followers to pray and to address  their prayers to His father in the heavens.

Matthew 6:9-10 NASB

9 “Pray, then, in this way: [a]Hallowed be Your name.10 [b]Your kingdom come.Your will be done,[c]On earth as it is in heaven.

Conclusion: Jesus will prepare a place  for his followers in the heavens.